# How to execute a Google Cloud Function through PHP?

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to execute a Google Cloud Function and wait for it's results through PHP?

I have searched the documentations at:

- https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php
- https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io
- https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

But none had integration for Cloud Functions.

Comment: Your question fits best at a sister site, selected from here: https://stackexchange.com/sites#

Comment: @ZF007 - This question fits on StackOverflow as it is a programming question. He does not need to move his post.

Comment: @ZF007 I think StackOverflow fits best

Comment: At **"learn more"** below on https://cloud.google.com/php/?hl=en page you'll stumble upon the php stuff... including a PHP SDK for it. Finding took me 10 seconds (incl. getting a grasp if it's looking relevant). So.. does this question still fits here on SO...

Comment: Google has a fairly good set of PHP SDKs for most Google Cloud services. Cloud Functions is not one of them. https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference/ However, Cloud Functions can be called from HTTP Triggers, which means that you can use any good HTTP library (such as Guzzle) to call Cloud Functions and wait for the result. Otherwise you can use the low level API and use HTTP requests in PHP: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions I am posting as a comment in case Google has something that I am not aware of that has not been announced.

Comment: Invoking an HTTP type Cloud Function is just a matter of making an HTTP request, which should have plenty of tutorials and documentation elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for pointing the reference out, helped a lot. My only problem now is that my function requires a user to be authenticated, i'm checking if context.auth exists. How can I authenticate using PHP request and my service_account json file? Should I open a new SO question for that?

Comment: Yes. Include details on the type of authentication. I have written articles on how to generate Access Tokens from service account credentials on my website. The examples are in Python and curl but you can port these to PHP very easily. If you make your new question clear enough, I might do the port myself to enhance my articles or write a new article on how to call Cloud Functions from a PHP website. https://www.jhanley.com/

Comment: @JohnHanley I would be very grateful if you could help me out at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54797672/call-cloud-function-that-requires-authentication-using-service-account-json-in-p I have added my code, that seems to fail

Answer (score 2):

You can create an HTTP triggered Cloud Function. For more information go to [HTTP Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http) documentation. Then make an http request form your PHP code using the function's trigger URL. To see it go to `Cloud Functions` page in Google Cloud Console. Click on your Cloud Function's name and the `Function details` page will open. Go to the `Trigger` tab and under `URL` you can see the link to execute the Cloud Function.

An PHP example to do so could be as follows (It is one of many, and that is what worked for me):
Run `sudo apt-get install php-curl` to install php curl

Use the following PHP code:

```
<?php
global $url;

//The Cloud Function's trigger URL
$url = "www.[FUNCTION_ZONE]-[PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net/[FUNCTION_NAME]";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Get the response and close the channel.
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo "Printing response: \n\n";
echo $response;
curl_close($ch);
```