# Call Firebase Cloud Function that requires Authentication using service_account json in PHP

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to execute a Google Cloud Function through PHP, but failing to authenticate when all I have is the service_account json file.

I'm using GuzzleHttp as the function returns a Promise.

What I did so far:

```
use Google\Auth\Credentials\ServiceAccountCredentials;
use Google\Auth\Middleware\AuthTokenMiddleware;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

$scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
];
$credentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials($scopes, [
    'client_email' => "<email>",
    'client_id' => "<client_id">,
            'private_key' => "<private_key>",
        ]);
$googleAuthTokenMiddleware = new AuthTokenMiddleware($credentials);
$stack = HandlerStack::create();
$stack->push($googleAuthTokenMiddleware);
$config = array('handler' => $stack,'auth' => 'google_auth');
$httpClient = new Client($config);
$promise = $httpClient->requestAsync("POST", "<function_url>", ['json' => ['data' => ""]]);
$promise->then(
    function (ResponseInterface $res) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($res->getBody());
        echo "</pre>";
    },
    function (RequestException $e) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($e->getRequest()->getHeaders());
        echo "</pre>";
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        echo $e->getRequest()->getMethod();
    }
);
$promise->wait();
```

### References:

**ServiceAccountCredentials:** From *namespace Google\Auth\Credentials;*

**AuthTokenMiddleware:** From *namespace Google\Auth\Middleware;*

**HandlerStack:** From *GuzzleHttp*

**Client:** From *GuzzleHttp*

### Http Response From Above Code

```
`401 Unauthorized` response: {"error":{"status":"UNAUTHENTICATED","message":"Unauthenticated"}} POST
```

### My Cloud Function

My Cloud Function checks for authentication as follow:

```
exports.testFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if (!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' +
            'while authenticated.');
    }

   return "Hooraaay!";
});
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I successfully authenticate?

Comment: Add information about how authorization is handled by your Cloud Function. For testing, create a new dummy function that returns similar data but does not have authorization (divide by 2 debugging). Also include the top part of your code that shows your library include statements.

Comment: @JohnHanley Hey! I have added my library references as well as my cloud function.

Comment: @JohnHanley Just tried it on a function that requires no auth, and simply replies with hello responded with the same error  `401 Unauthorized` response: {"error":{"status":"UNAUTHENTICATED","message":"Unauthenticated"}}.
Weird I think

Comment: OK - I just noticed the keyword Firebase. I have not worked with Firebase authentication for Cloud Functions (context.auth). I am not sure what headers Firebase uses and the values. I believe it is `Authorization: Bearer token` but I am not sure.

Comment: Trigger your dummy function in the Google Cloud Console. What happens?

Comment: The function works perfectly on my mobile app that is using Googl's SDK. Its only through PHP that is not working

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how Firebase Cloud Function authenticate using the client_id and private_key

Comment: In this question you can find out the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54818119/google-php-api-client-i-keep-getting-error-401-unauthenticated

Comment: You can find the solution in my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54818119/google-php-api-client-i-keep-getting-error-401-unauthenticated